# linkedin API cannot create campaign

Tags: linkedin-api, ads

We have got `rw_ads` permissions for an app. Through that app We have taken access_token with all given permissions.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns), we have `rw_ads` permission, but If we try to create/update campaign we are getting the below error.

> {
>       "serviceErrorCode": 100,
>       "message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /adCampaignsV2/sdafnk",
>       "status": 403 }

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2/sdafnk',
  headers: 
   { 'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: 
   { patch: 
      { '$set': 
         { runSchedule: { end: 1548405000000, start: 1547713800000 },
           status: 'ACTIVE' } } },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Code for creation of campaign is mentioned below

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <accessToken>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
  },
  body: { 
    account: 'urn:li:sponsoredAccount:<accountId>',
    audienceExpansionEnabled: false,
    costType: 'CPM',
    creativeSelection: 'OPTIMIZED',
    dailyBudget: { amount: '200', currencyCode: 'INR' },
    locale: { country: 'IN', language: 'en' },
    name: 'Campaign text ad test',
    objectiveType: 'WEBSITE_TRAFFIC',
    offsiteDeliveryEnabled: false,
    runSchedule: { end: 1547708400000, start: 1547967600000 },
    type: 'TEXT_AD',
    unitCost: { amount: '10', currencyCode: 'INR' },
    status: 'PAUSED' 
  },
  json: true 
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a partial update, the header `X-RestLi-Method` must be included in the request and set to `PARTIAL_UPDATE`.

Also if you use implicit grant-type, check if you have defined the scope correctly at the start. if you use client-credentials grant-type check if the account has the right permissions.

> Direct Sponsored Content can be created by:
>
> Ad Account Users with a role higher than `VIEWER`. Organization users
>   with `DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER or ADMINISTRATOR roles`.

also the code you added in this question is for **Reactivating** a campaign. not for **updating/creating** one.

Comment: I have tried creating and updating, have got similar response for that also

Comment: could you share the account role ? this information can be found on the page wherefor you want to create a campaign.

Comment: Role is Account Manager

Comment: is this the role of your ad account or organization account ?

Comment: role is for ad account

Comment: what oauth strategy do you use and have you added rw_ad to the scope ?

Comment: By using 3-legged OAuth as mentioned here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context)

Comment: have you tried to GET a campaign ? maybe you could try it to see if you do have permissions for that.

Comment: Get campaign is working fine, anything related to create or update is not working

Comment: what type of campaign are you trying to create ?

Comment: I am trying to create Text_ad

Comment: Can you share the code you use for creating and changing a post ?
because all these thing you just mentioned all same good to me. the only thing you can try is removing rw_ad from your scope and then try to create an ad.

Comment: i found an old link from AD creating. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/ads/adcampaigns#create 

there are some parameters in your list that arent allowed in the old documentation. could you change these and check if it works.

( this is a longshot ) but apart from this i do not know what its wrong with it. have you tried reaching out to the support of linkedin ?

Comment: Tried with old documentation also, but no change. Posted in linkedin Help Forum

Comment: Your application will need to authorize access tokens with the `rw_ads` permission in order to create and manage campaigns. If your application needs read only access please use `r_ads`. If you are using legacy permissions, please refer to this page for requesting legacy permissions.

Are you sure you have `rw_ads` and not `r_ads` ? Because that would explain a lot..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186843/discussion-between-vishnu-and-lars-hendriks).